# create user's view profile link with username

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have created user's view  profile page. when any user click on member name then it's redirect to view-profile page and open  clicked user info. I have changed url using `add_rewrite_rule()` . So my current view-profile page link like below

```
http://site_url/view-profile/username
```

But i want to url like below

```
http://site_url/username
```

see below code for link

```
add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_tags');
function dcc_rewrite_tags() {
         add_rewrite_tag('%user%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
     add_rewrite_rule('^view-profile/(.+)/?$','index.php?page_id=pageID&user=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find out following answer:

```
  add_action('init','change_all_permalinks');
  function change_all_permalinks()
  {
      global $wp_rewrite;
      $wp_rewrite->author_base = ''; 
      $wp_rewrite->author_structure = '/%author%';
   }
```

After add this code in functions.php you need to go permalink settings and  press on save changes button,without change anything in permalinks and then check frontend url 'www.yoursite/admin/'.

Comment: it's not working. When i add this code, all permalink changed. Only homepage working and other pages are given 404 page